# Python Reusing Child Process for Another Method

Tags: python, multithreading, machine-learning, multiprocessing

Let's say I implement multi-processing and create a process like so on one method. Is there any way that I can then use the same process to call another method?

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1, args=(input,))
process_list.append(p)
p.start() # start thread execution
```

Some background information: I have a function (let's call it func_load) that loads some large machine learning models (takes a couple minutes) and then another function (let's call it func_infer) to perform inference on the models in real-time. I'd like to first call the func_load function in a setup stage and then call the func_infer function later on due to the time aspect.

I'd really like to be able to implement multiprocessing for that. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do that?

Thanks!